# subadditive function example

Tags: functions, derivatives

Can somebody give me an example of a continuous function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Such that 
$$\frac{\partial F(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_i} \geq 0 \;\; \forall x_i, \;i=1,2$$
but, 
$$
\frac{\partial F(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} < 0
$$

Comment: yes. but the function can be piecewise defined.

Comment: Subadditive? What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $F(x_1,x_2)=-e^{-x_1-x_2}$?